# How can i check that incoming request is of browser, ajax or of REST call in PHP?

Tags: php, rest

Basically i want to detect that the incoming http request is coming from a browser ? I want to stop all other robot calls through web services and ajax ?

Comment: You *could* check the user agent header. But this can easily be forged. Forbid robots in `robots.txt`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: @LutzHorn I want to detect it in php code. I tried USER_AGENT header but there is a long list of them.

Comment: @PankajGarg how about, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` ? and have a look at this long list: http://www.user-agents.org/

Comment: @majidarif: I have tried this and already seen this solution but isn't there a better way to easily detect the type of the incoming http request so that i can program accordingly ?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps : [Detecting-Ajax](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax)

Comment: First, I just want to allow only calls from Browser. So detecting ajax is not the complete solution. Second, you can manually set this by curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));

Comment: Please mention at least `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` in the answer, that will make it much better. People actually use stackoverflow as a reference, and the other page may go down.

Comment: The browser is just a computer program, whatever it can do, another (evil) robot can also do. To identify human visitors you need something like CAPTCHA. @PankajGarg What level of protection do you need? Just from benign Web-crawlers or evil attackers?

Comment: @MKaama -> Just from benign Web-crawlers or evil attackers? Yes but I was looking for a gentle detection between these requests if possible. But If you suggest for saving from attacks, will work!

Answer (score 1):

### Benign WEB-crawlers and polite AJAX sites

will not hide their true identity. These two headers should suffice to check:

- `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` — by the very presence of the header (credit goes to [Nataraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754161/nataraj))
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` — you must collect a list of typical substrings to tell robots and browsers apart

Many respect **/robots.txt**, [Tichodroma muraria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1907906/tichodroma-muraria) gave you an excellent reference, he should have posted an answer.

### Sly and evil robots

escalate the battle to a completely different level, but you can outwit them too, if you put in more effort than the bot developers are willing to. E.g. you can

- **throttle** requests from the same IP
- check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, or, in the absence of any,
- keep a history of recent hits and only serve sub-resources if there was a request for the main page from the same **IP** with the same **HTTP headers**
- constantly change the links or some security parameters in the main page and only answer requests with recent security tokens. Encode a hash of requesters IP in the **security parameter** to thwart distributed abuse of your site
- create some cryptographic hashes in complex client-side **javascript**, something that modern browsers can do, but simple bots cannot
- if the hit volumes are high, record full HTTP headers and study **statistics** to discover patterns by which robots differ from human visitors. I think that is the limit of what you can do without disturbing valid human users of your site
- go ahead and ask for **CAPTCHA**.

By security parameters I mean something like

http://example.com/?param=78364528 
, where **param** is derived by some nontrivial calculation from *salt*, visitor's IP adress, day of year, *sessionid* cookie, *User-Agent string* and maybe something else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this technique if you are relying on it to be safe. Because the headers can be spoofed by a malicious user! This might not apply to your situation, but maybe to other users viewing this Q&A.